# Searching information about Java EE app and Alfresco

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, lucene, search-engine, alfresco

We have a **Java EE management application** with one database. We currently work to **move the documents** of our application **to Alfresco** community 4.2, but these documents are linked to our MySQL Data.

**What is the strategy about searching information in the two databases** (both are MySQL DB) **?**

*For exemple, if a client wants to search the documentary evidences of the accounting operations for a period. The accounting operations are located on Application DB but the documentary evidences would be on Alfresco MySQL DB. Can Lucene make that possible if the accounting operation id is added to the metadata of documentary evidences? SOLR ? Should we merge the two DB ? What is the best strategy to apply ?*

Answer (score 1):

1st of all: don't access Alfresco DB directly!

Use an API to CRUD the documents in Alfresco, e.g. CMIS.
In your use case:

> The accounting operations are located on Application DB but the
>   documentary evidences would be on Alfresco MySQL DB

I would create a content-model in Alfresco incl. the document(node) properties you would like able to search for and just save your binary documents + the relevant meta-data in Alfresco.
Then use Alfresco's search API (powered by SOLR) to find the documents.

Comment: If I understand well your solution, I will have to duplicate in Alfresco the document properties which as already stored in the application database.

Back to my example about searching the documentary evidences of the accounting operations over a given period, I will have to store both in Alfresco and in the Application the accouting operations dates.

Could it be possible to use an alternative solution, avoiding to duplicate application data in Alfresco ? For instance, by storing in Alfresco only the reference of the accounting operation ?

Comment: of course you can just save a reference - the best solution depends on your detailed requirements but never access Alfresco's DB directly! make us of the APIs

Comment: Of course, we only intend to use Alfresco's APIs.
But our question is rather : can Alfresco search on our application DB ? And if it's possible, what's the best way ?

Comment: no, not OOTB - you will have to index your data in Alfresco's index (not recommended to do this directly) or create another search index will you index you data sources as you like or implement a federated search (search in more than 1 index)